# Show that spectral norm of A is spectral norm of A transpose

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I've been trying to prove this rather small expression, but I can't get anywhere.

I have to show that :

For $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}, A$ is regular:

$ ||A||_2 = ||A^T||_2 $

I think the trick is to show that $A^T = AA^T$, however all I get is that $I=(A^TA)^{-1} AA^T$ which is only possible when $A^T = AA^T$, but I don't think that's the right answer since I'm using my initial hypothesis to prove it.

What could be another direction to go ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As spectral norm and spectral radius are connected by $$\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}=\rho\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\A^T&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ you only need to prove something like $\rho(AB)=\rho(BA)$, which you have perhaps already done.